# Interface between user and storage file system

Tags: network-storage

I'm going to have a server with loads of storage space on it, that will be accessible to multiple users on the network. I'm looking for a program that will enforce the users, whenever they save a new file of change an existing one, to enter certain details about the file. I want those details to be written by this program to a small file near the file that the user adds (although other ways of storing those details might work too).

In short it's some sort of interface between the nentwork users and the server's file system.

Does anyone know of anything of the sort? (Better if free but not a must).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a document management system, I don't know of anything that works exactly how you have specified. However [Sharepoint 2007 Document Libraries](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA011412871033.aspx) will give you the ability to require meta data for individual files added to it. If you are using windows there is reasonably good integration with Windows Explorer and Office 2007+.

Windows Sharepoint Services (WSS) is part of your Windows Server 2003+ Client Access Licences so assuming you have Windows Server and the CALs for your users to access it there will be no additional cost.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an OpenSource CMS that follows more or less your requirements, have a look at Alfresco (http://www.alfresco.com/). Alfresco lets you expose your documents via CIFS (Windows file sharing) which lets you browse the documents as a standard network share.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are trying to implement your own [document management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system) or [Content management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). After all, even if you can implement your metadata scheme, you'll have to parse those files, make them searchable, index them etc...

So I'd recommend to look at existing solutions that fit your needs. That might be a wiki, or a DMS. There are several free and paid applications available in both categories.

I personally would recommend a wiki, but that may not fit your needs. Also be aware that if you want a network filesystem as the user interfaces, Windows shares are not your only option. A WebDAV share might also fit the need, and be better supported by DMSes.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a document management software is best solution for you can try [Content Central](http://www.ademero.com).
you can get Online Preview.